# Lazy loading using MEAN stack (AngularJS 1.x)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

how to implement lazy loading/more data on scroll with MEAN stack. I want to load 10 posts at a time, when I scroll down, the next 10 elements should load.

The following code is showing all the list of users:

```
exports.findAllUsers = function (req, res) {
User.find(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Users not Find.." + err);
        res.json({ success: false, "data": err });
    }
    else {
        console.log("Users Finds.. " + data);
        res.json({ success: true, "data": data });
    }
});
};
```

I have tried the lazy loading using following code: but I am getting this error (Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.)

```
var itemsPerPage = 6;

exports.findAllUsers = function (req, res, pageNum) {

User.find({skip: (itemsPerPage * (pageNum-1)), limit: itemsPerPage}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Users not Find.." + err);
        res.json({ success: false, "data": err });
    }
    else {
        console.log("Users Finds.. " + data);
        res.json({ success: true, "data": data });
    }
});
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you hit the endpoint that employs the findAllUsers function, how are you enumerating pageNum? Are you parsing out the pageNum from the request in the same code that ties the route to the function somehow?

Comment: I just followed the "Skip method" from mongoose docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#cursor.skip

Comment: Ok, but that's not what I'm asking. Your `findAllUsers` method signature has a `pageNum` parameter that I don't see being initialized. Based on your comment to the answer below, I'm guessing that you're no longer getting the "No default engine" error and are now only getting one result from your endpoint - which could be caused by `pageNum` being undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is nothing to do with throws routes,ist says that you didn't choose and set a [template engine](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) to your application.

You need to set it like so:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Or, if you want use a more easy to learn template engine, use ejs like so:

```
// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I have set up the view engine but the lazy loading/pagination is not working. I am not getting any errors as well.

The result at Terminal is:

user ID is : 56a736e5ecc25fc92b468045
data posted { _id: 56a736e5ecc25fc92b468045,
  userName: 'admin',
  userEmail: 'admin@admin.com',
  userPass: 'admin',
  __v: 0,
  Date: '1453799012529' }

Users Finds..

Comment: I mean it is waiting for the users data.@Elad

Comment: @NareshAithagoni Does that mean you are no longer getting the "No default engine" error after following Elad's suggestion? If so, perhaps you should accept this answer and open a new question regarding your new issue.

Comment: @Will Yes, I am not getting the **"No default engine"** error after following Elad's suggestion. Thank you Elad. Now, I am seeking help in _"lazy loading/pagination"_.  **I have a users list and questions list. I want to load 10 elements at a time, when I scroll down, the next 10 elements should load**. How to do it?. Please help me!

Comment: @NareshAithagoni ask the question as a **new** question in the site.i will thank you if you will mark my original answer as the correct  answer .

Comment: @Elad I can not ask a new question it seems because I am getting this **It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!**

Comment: Look up for this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days